# Converting a static formula to selection code VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm working on an record processing tool and have run into a problem.

One of our clients provides us with raw data that contains carriage breaks - making it unusable until formatted. Unfortunately the easy solution of running a clean function can't be used as it erases the last digit of the 16-digit account numbers in the process. Hoping that every end user remembers to keep destination formatting when porting the data over to have it formatted into text strings isn't really an option either.

So here's my plea for help:
I was able to get a clean value by using this formula

```
    =IF(RIGHT(A2,1)=" ",LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1),A2)
```

I now need to turn it into a macro that will change the cell.value of the selected cells to the result of the formula. But after 8 hours of banging my head against the wall I just can't figure out how to do it. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `TRIM` will remove the unwanted space.  `=TRIM(A2)` in VBA: `ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = Application.Trim(ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to everyone for such quick and informative responses!

I have managed to identify the issue - turns out as well as a carriage break the raw data also contained a tab space in front of the data that twas causing all the issues and was refusing to be edited by trim or manual edit! Here's the final code fr the macro button I embedded that solved the issue:

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Selection
    For Each cell In Rng
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) = False Then
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, Chr(9), "'")
    End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I've set the tab space to be replace by an apostrophe so that final value does not end up getting truncated, like what was happening when i used the clean function.

Once again many thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Your formula in VBA:

```
Sub Klean()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Selection
        v = Cell.Value
        If Right(v, 1) = " " Then
            v = Left(v, Len(v) - 1)
            Cell.Value = v
        End If
      Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a function that iterates over a given set of cells. You can call that function using whatever cells are currently selected.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoSomethingCool()

    CleanCellText Selection
    '--- or ---
    CleanCellText ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z20")

End Sub

Public Sub CleanCellText(ByRef thisRange As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In thisRange
        If Right$(cell.Value, 1) = " " Then
            cell.Value = Left$(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1)
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```